# How To Have VB.Net Installer Run My Code

Tags: vb.net, windows-installer

I have been searching online for an answer for this question, but cannot find anything useful in my case. I added deployment to my project, but I want that deployment to copy JavaScript files to a certain dynamic location. The only way I can think of is having the deployment call my function that I can write in VB.net. If you guys have any idea on how to do this or some other ideas it would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You're wrong. You don't need JavaScript or anything else. See [Custom Actions Management in Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbd7cck3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). You can also just add the JavaScript files as items that need to be installed, and specify a target location. Search [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) for `Deployment`, and you'll find lots of relevant hits. (If you're going to develop in Visual Studio, you should memorize the MSDN link.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I had a similar question to this, the easiest way is do this is...

1. Right-Click on the Solution, and go to Add - New Project.
2. New Project - (Setup/Deployment - Visual Studio Installer)
3. Under the "File System on Target Machine" - Add a new Folder that contains all the JavaScript items that you wish to deploy.
4. Change the Default Folder Location to your location that you intend for the Install process

For the folder properties for the Default Folder Location - use this link. It'll help a lot!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372057(v=vs.80).aspx

That's the basic idea from what I gathered about your post.

Best, 
Jimmy